# Ionide: how to specify FSharpLint's configuration?

Tags: f#, ionide

According to the [FSharpLint documentation](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/blob/master/docs/content/how-tos/rule-configuration.md), on the command line, you can specify the config file via `--lint-config`.

Since the tool comes integrated into Ionide, I was expecting some means of specifying the config file in that extension's settings. However, the only setting that's [documented](http://ionide.io/Editors/Code/options.html) is `FSharp.Linter`, which lets you turn the linter on or off.

Is there really no way to configure FSharpLint in Ionide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step example based on Koenig Lear's answer.

I have a codebase where some functions have underscores in the name. This was showing up as a linter issue:

[image]

Note that the rule code is `FL0049`.

The rule list is here:

https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpLint/how-tos/rule-configuration.html

If I click on the rule for FL0049, we're taken to the following page:

https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpLint/how-tos/rules/FL0049.html

We're shown an example of how to configure this rule:

```
{
    "publicValuesNames": {
        "enabled": true,
        "config": {
            "underscores": "AllowPrefix"
        }
    }
}
```

I see in the notes that `underscores` can be set to `AllowAny`.

I create an `fsharplint.json` file in my project root directory with the following contents:

```
{
    "conventions": {
        "naming": {
            "publicValuesNames": {
                "enabled": true,
                "config": {
                    "underscores": "AllowAny"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I close the my F# code file, re-open it, and the squigglies are gone. :-)

Comment: Worth noting that now your linter is checking only that one single rule https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/issues/488

Answer (score 2):

You can create a *fsharplint.json* file at the root of your project.  I'd start with this example : https://github.com/microsoft/fsharplu/blob/master/fsharplint.json.

You can then tweak the options at your leisure.  Be sure to restart VSCode for the changes to take effect.

Comment: OK, I'm currently not using Ionide because of this, I'll try your suggestion